# api is evaluated to null in freemaker

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I'm testing the [freemarker template injection issue](https://ackcent.com/in-depth-freemarker-template-injection/), I created a springboot project with

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.31</version>
        </dependency>
```

And a controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/freemarker")
public class FreeMarkerController {
    private String run(String template, String username, Boolean hardened) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("username", username);
        }};

        StringTemplateLoader tempLoader = new StringTemplateLoader();
        tempLoader.putTemplate("test", template);

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31);
        if (hardened)
            cfg.setNewBuiltinClassResolver(TemplateClassResolver.SAFER_RESOLVER);
        cfg.setTemplateLoader(tempLoader);
        cfg.setAPIBuiltinEnabled(true);

        Template tmpl = cfg.getTemplate("test");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        tmpl.process(data, writer);

        return writer.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/unsafe")
    public String parse_unsfe(@RequestParam(name="template", required=true) String template) throws Exception {
        return run(template, "test", false);
    }
}
```

However, this results in an error because api is undefined

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/freemarker/unsafe -d 'template=<#assign classLoader=object?api.class.protectionDomain.classLoader>'
```

Error in console

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> object  [in template "test" at line 1, column 22]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----
```

Why is api undefined? I already enabled API builtins. Does anyone know?

Comment: The error message says that it's `object` that's missing/null, and not `?api`.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam` is queryString of param
Try this

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/freemarker/unsafe?template=abc
```

But you have special symbols in template so you should use `@RequestBody` for it

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/unsafe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String parse_unsfe(@RequestBody String template) throws Exception {
    return run(template, "test", false);
}
```

And use this curl command

```
curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:8080/freemarker/unsafe -d 
"<#assign classLoader=object?api.class.protectionDomain.classLoader>"
```